# Problem fetching data extensions from child business units using server to server token via SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, soap-api, accesstoken

I am currently working on a solution where I can read/write to data extensions in the following folders using a **user access token**.

1. Data Extensions
2. Shared Data Extensions
3. Salesforce Data Extensions

However, I have specific scenarios where I need to use a **server-to-server** token to read/write into these folders and for some reason, when I use server-server token I am only able to fetch data extensions in **Shared Data Extensions** folder and I cannot find data extensions in the other folders.

Note:

- I can fetch data extensions in all folders when querying from a parent BU, this behavior occurs only in **child BUs**.
- queryAllAccounts is true, so I can fetch shared data extensions.

Does anyone have any idea why I am experiencing this?

Comment: are you passing account ID in the token call to operate in the context of that account?

Comment: @EazyE Yes! I am passing the business unit ID as account ID when requesting server-to-server token

Comment: When you're working in the context of a child business unit (BU), the scope of data extensions available to the Server-to-Server API may be limited to those that are local to the BU or shared. Data extensions that belong to another BU might not be accessible. If you are still facing issues, can you add more details to your question?